# Tic tac toe 4x4 game 2x2 grouping win algorithm

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, logic, tic-tac-toe

Hello I am creating a basic tic tac toe game for my own pleasure that has 4x4 fields I have the program pretty much completed but I am stuck on one part in my game i have to decide a winner if any x's or o's are grouped by 2x2 i already have the horizontal and vertical and diagonal algorithms to decide a winner completed 
so for example if we have

```
        x|x|o|o
        x|x|o|x
         | | | 
         | | |
```

X will be the winner since he has a 2x2 group
thank you for any help!

example code for my vertical winner code

```
                   public boolean checkForWin()
    {
        char symbol = SYMBOL[turn];

        //check vertical win
        Check1:
            for(int i=0; i<BOARD_SIZE; i++)
            {
                for(int j=0; j<BOARD_SIZE; j++)
                    if(board[i][j] != symbol)
                        continue Check1;
                //if reached, winning line found
                return true;
            }
        //check horizontal win
        Check2:
            for(int j=0; j<BOARD_SIZE; j++)
            {
                for(int i=0; i<BOARD_SIZE; i++)
                    if(board[i][j] != symbol)
                        continue Check2;
                //if reached, winning line found
                return true;
            }


            //check back slash diagonal win q
            for(int i=0; i<BOARD_SIZE; i++)
                if(board[i][i] != symbol)
                    break;
                else if(i == BOARD_SIZE-1) 
                    return true; // winning line found
            //check forward slash diagonal win
            for(int i=0; i<BOARD_SIZE; i++)
                if(board[i][BOARD_SIZE - i - 1] != symbol) 
                    break;
                else if(i == BOARD_SIZE-1) 
                    return true; // winning line found
            //if reach here then no win found
            return false;
    }
```

where would i input that code ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of winning configurations each having 4 locations. There are 4 winning rows, 4 winning columns, 2 diagonals, and 9 blocks. Then just check each configuration.

Code would be roughly

```
// Set this up once at the start
WinningConfiguration[] allWinningConfigurations = {
  WinningConfiguration.row(0),
  ...
  WinningConfiguration.row(3);
  WinningConfiguration.column(0);
  ...
  WinningConfiguration.column(3);
  WinningConfiguration.block(0,0);
  ...
  WinningConfiguration.block(3,3);
  WinningConfiguration.diagonal();        
  WinningConfiguration.reversedDiagonal();
}

..

// Now all your checks, (row, column, diagonal and blocks) become
for(WinningConfiguration config : allWinningConfigurations) {
  boolean configWins = true;
  for(int i=0; i<4; ++i) {
    if(board[config.pts[i].x][config.pts[i].y]!=symbol) {
       configWins = false;
       break;
    }
  }
  if(configWins)
    return true;
}
return false;
```

And if you then want to add other winning combinations (say all four corners) you only need to add one row to your winning Configurations array and you're done.

There's further refactoring that could be done to make this neater too, like moving the check into the `WinningConfiguration` class so that the loop becomes

```
for(WinningConfiguration config : allWinningConfigurations) {
  if(config.wins(symbol)
    return true;
}
return false;
```

Comment: @linyu21 it's not a copy-and-paste solution. I'm not doing _all_ your work for you ;) Its just outlining what I think is a good way to structure your code so that the check becomes easy.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way: EVERY winning 2x2 square will have a topleft corner. So if you see a mark, you can check to see if the square to the right, bottom, and bottomright are all the same type, and if so, marker that player a winner. Since you're starting your check on the topleft corner, you never need to put a starter check on the rightmost or bottommost lines (because you won't have a square extend outside your board!)

So for int i extending from 0 to BOARD_SIZE-1, and for int j extending from 0 to BOARD_SIZE-1, if board[i][j] == board[i+1][j] == board[i][j+1] == board[i+1][j+1] == symbol then you have yourself a winner.

There are a few things you could do beyond that to make it a bit more efficient, but since it's tic-tac-toe I don't think you're too concerned with scalability =)

Comment: so i would do                                                                                                                               for(int i=0; i<BOARD_SIZE-1; i++)
    {
    for(int j=0; j<BOARD_SIZE-1; j++)     if  ( board[i][j] == board[i+1][j] == board[i][j+1] == board[i+1][j+1] == symbol)  ;  return true        ?

Comment: I was writing psuedocode. It'll probably be easier for you to understand if you do it on 4 separate lines.

Comment: just tried that code and it ended up not displaying any of the x's or o's on the board when i inputted them each turn

Comment: Or rather, it has to be one operation. Seems like a good place for the "&&" command. "if(board[i][j] == symbol && board[i+1][j] == symbol && ....) return true;"